# Magento "Special Price From Date" not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, magento, cron

We use Magento 1.7.0.2.

Now we have a promotion calendar with products (offline) which should be visible for one day as a promotion on the frontpage of the shop.

We have two attributes "Special Price From Date" and "Special Price To Date" with the date on which the product should be displayed on the home page.
We also have an attribute "Special Price" in which we enter the promotional price .

Example:

```
Today is 09.12.2013

"Price" = 200
"Special Price" = 180

"Special Price From Date" = 10.12.2013
"Special Price To Date" = 10.12.2013
```

Now the product should be displayed on the home page and available for the special price of 180 on 10.12.2013.

If I search the product on 10.12.2013 via category filter in the frontend the price of the product is actually reduced to 180 as it should be. The problem is now that the product is indeed displayed on 10.12.2013 on the front page, but with the old price of 200.

I have found a solution for that: I have to wait until the day concerned, edit the product and then click "Save" again. Then the product appears on the home page with the promotional price. But you may understant that we can not save each affected product every day again. The "Special Price From Date" should exactly do that, shouldn't it?

What I have already tried:

```
- Call cron.php via cronjob call 1x per day
- Call indexer.php reindexall via cronjob 1x per day
- Calling a script 1x per day via cronjob which deletes all caches
```

Unfortunately everything does not work.
Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

I thought about corrupted tables or stuff like that, what about executing a script like that once a day?

```
$tables = $db->query('SHOW TABLES');

foreach ($tables as $table)
{
    $db->query("ANALYZE TABLE {$table}");
    $db->query("OPTIMIZE TABLE {$table}");
}
```

Comment: can you share the code responsible for showing the special products on home page ?

Comment: Have you disabled block cache?

Comment: yes i have disabled all caches for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento have already cron to reindex catalog price (catalog_product_index_price_reindex_all) and delete all cache (core_clean_cache).

You need to check, these cron are running properly or not.

OR

You can install this cron scheduler free extension (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html) to watch all cron activity and find out issue.

Hope will help!

Comment: Ok I will install the extension and check the cronjobs. Tomorrow I will be able to see if it works and replay here.